# Dask data loading on local cluster: "Worker exceeded 95% memory budget". Restarting and then "KilledWorker"

Tags: memory-management, bigdata, cluster-computing, worker, dask-dataframe

I know similar questions have been asked before but their solutions were not very helpful. I guess the best solution is probably more specific to each cluster configuration, so I'm putting more details here about my cluster and my error.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.bag as db
import json

from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster()
client = Client(cluster)
```

Here are my cluster settings

```
cluster.scheduler
```

#output:

```
Scheduler: tcp://127.0.0.1:35367 workers: 8 cores: 48 tasks: 0



cluster.workers
```

#output:

```
{0: <Nanny: tcp://127.0.0.1:43789, threads: 6>,
 1: <Nanny: tcp://127.0.0.1:41375, threads: 6>,
 2: <Nanny: tcp://127.0.0.1:42577, threads: 6>,
 3: <Nanny: tcp://127.0.0.1:40171, threads: 6>,
 4: <Nanny: tcp://127.0.0.1:32867, threads: 6>,
 5: <Nanny: tcp://127.0.0.1:46529, threads: 6>,
 6: <Nanny: tcp://127.0.0.1:41535, threads: 6>,
 7: <Nanny: tcp://127.0.0.1:39645, threads: 6>}


client
```

#output

```
Client
Scheduler: tcp://127.0.0.1:35367
Dashboard: http://127.0.0.1:8787/status
Cluster
Workers: 8
Cores: 48
Memory: 251.64 GiB
```

Here are my data loading codes:

```
b = db.read_text('2019-12-16-latest-level.json').map(json.loads)

def flatten(record):
    return {
        'uuid': record['uuid'],
        'stored_at': record['stored_at'],
        'duration': record['duration']
}
```

All codes above run fine. Here is the one that got in trouble:

```
df = b.map(flatten).to_dataframe()
df.head()
```

The codes run for around 1 day and gave the warning below:

```
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
```

Then around another day, the program stopped and gave me the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KilledWorker                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-84f98622da69> in <module>
      1 df = b.map(flatten).to_dataframe()
----> 2 df.head()
```

And here are the last few lines of the error report:

```
KilledWorker: ("('bag-from-delayed-file_to_blocks-list-loads-flatten-0daa9cba16c635566df6215c209f653c', 0)", <WorkerState 'tcp://127.0.0.1:41535', name: 6, memory: 0, processing: 1>)
```

Screenshots of the full error report is also attached:
[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]
[image: screenshot3]
[image: screenshot4]

Any suggestions on how to deal with this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been using dask, with mixed results, for about a month now. My personal belief is that the software has some kind of deadly embrace in its memory management when executing task graphs. A typical *modus operandi* of dask is to compute 95% of a large computation in just a few minutes, then spend the next 8 hours crunching away at the last 5% appearing to do nothing before it crashes or I run out of compute budget. This is very frustrating.

That said, I have had *some* limited success using fewer workers or confining workers to processes rather than threads. So, on a 16 core machine I might do:

```
client = Client(processes=True, threads_per_worker=1)
```

Another important thing to do is persist intelligently. Persisting causes there to be fewer tasks in the graph (and as a result in memory) at a given time. So if I want to read a bag from a json file, I would persist the bag before converting to a dataframe, otherwise the reading and conversion both happen at the compute() step and I find that is a recipe for failure.

However, as I said, I have found dask quite disappointing, considering all it appears on the surface to be capable of. I'm switching to vaex instead.

Sorry I was unable to help more.

Comment: Thanks. I switched to build a database using python. It took several days but eventually works. I may also look up vaex then.